# Save the login state of the user

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication, sharedpreferences, logout

I want that application allows user to login for the first time. And then when user exit the application without logging out, user will be brought back to the same place or layout which comes after the login layout even if user start the application again. But if user logout from the application, user will be brought back to the main login screen.

From Launcher(splash screen)----->(App)Login page--->(App)Home screen

From Home app----->(App)Home screen

if click logout button

From Launcher(splash screen)----->(App)Login page--->(App)Home screen

```
My Splash screen code :----

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;

    public class splash_start extends Activity{
        Handler handler = new Handler() {

           };


        protected void onCreate(Bundle var1) {
            super.onCreate(var1);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.splash);
Intend intend =new Intend (splash.this,login.class);
startactivity(intend)}


        this.handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 2000L);


        }

    }


    my login.java code :----

    public class log_inn extends Activity {
        EditText uname, pass;
        Button login;
        String username, password;
        String loginid;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        Intent in;
           SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.log_in);
            uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                        .permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }



            pass.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

                     @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                            KeyEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                             login.performClick();
                             return true;
                         }


                        return false;
                    }
                 });



            login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    username = uname.getText().toString().trim();
                    password = pass.getText().toString().trim();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you tried `SharedPreference`?

Comment: Please add more information: Are you logging in with Facebook, Google or some other 3rd party API? Because they manage this kind of thing for you with a Session token.

Comment: actually i am making android application for courier company in which the driver will login the application and will show online on the server to the admin. even they close the application driver will show online till driver don't click on logout button in the application.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the login state in the `SharedPreferences`. In the `onStart` of your activity, check the value of the `sharedPreference` and react accordingly to the login state.

After the user logged in :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.userlogged), true); // false on logout
editor.commit();
```

In your `onStart` method : (or onResume, or whatever fits for you)

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
bool defaultValue = false
bool isUserLogged = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.userlogged, defaultValue); 

if(isUseerLogged) {
    // Do something for the logged user
} else {
    // Do something for the unlogged user
}
```

Comment: You should also delete that data when user logs out.

Comment: I added an example for you, inspired by the official documentation which you should look at when you have such question http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html